# PanelControl gets a NullReferenceException when passed to a Class Constructor

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on borderless forms in vb.net and I'm trying to make my forms draggable using the panel control to handle form events. (like mouseup, mousedown, etc.)

I created a `Draggable` Class to handle this, I tried using the class with the form object and it drags the form perfectly. But when I passed the panel object in the constructor I got this.

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user code
```

May I know why I always get the nullreference exception? I tried instantiating the panel it still it doesn't work.

**Update**

I added `Option Strict On` on my code as Sir Mark Hall suggested. It showed implicit conversion of object and panel so I had to set `TargetObject` parameter as Panel

Here's the updated code. It's still giving the same exception. I wonder if panels have `MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove` events declared once I passed it on the class?

**Draggable.vb**

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Draggable
    Dim drag As Boolean
    Dim mousex As Integer
    Dim mousey As Integer
    Dim ctrlPanel As New Panel()

    Public Sub New(ByVal TargetObject As Panel)
        ctrlPanel = Nothing
        ctrlPanel = DirectCast(TargetObject, Panel)
        Try
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseDown, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseDown)
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseMove, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseMove)
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseUp, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseUp)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisForm_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        drag = True
        mousex = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - ctrlPanel.Left
        mousey = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - ctrlPanel.Top
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisForm_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If drag Then
            ctrlPanel.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
            ctrlPanel.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - mousex
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisForm_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        drag = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Main.vb**

```
Public Class Main
    'Dim draggablePanel As New Draggable(ControlPanel)

#Region "Draggable Form"
    Dim drag As Boolean
    Dim mousex As Integer
    Dim mousey As Integer
    Dim ctrlPanel As Panel

    Private Sub ControlPanel_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ControlPanel.MouseDown
        drag = True
        mousex = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
        mousey = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
    End Sub

    Private Sub ControlPanel_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ControlPanel.MouseMove
        If drag Then
            Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
            Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - mousex
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ControlPanel_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ControlPanel.MouseUp
        drag = False
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub btnMaximize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMaximize.Click
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Else
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMinimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinimize.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenu.Click
        If pnlNav.Visible = False Then
            pnlNav.Show()
        Else
            pnlNav.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUser.Click
        pnlWelcomeScreen.Hide()
        pnlSecurity.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOptions_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOptions.Click
        If pnlBottomOptions.Visible = False Then
            pnlBottomOptions.Show()
        Else
            pnlBottomOptions.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Where the Exception is coming from**

```
Public Sub New(ByVal TargetObject As Panel)
    ctrlPanel = Nothing
    ctrlPanel = DirectCast(TargetObject, Panel)
    Try
        this one here -> AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseDown, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseDown) 'this one here
        AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseMove, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseMove)
        AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseUp, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseUp)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Screenshot of the Form**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1AyzK5zBH9ZNUN0eF9YcGRna2M/edit?usp=sharing

thank you for all your opinions and help..

Comment: Is it a form or a panel, big difference...

Comment: If it's a form fine, but in that class your setting the object as a form, if it's not a form there's the problem...

Comment: please turn [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), it looks like you are doing some implicit casting.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR yes sir, i tried the same functions directly inside my vb forms and it worked, using panels to drag the form

Comment: what is/where is that Class Main?  Its hard to tell whether you are messing with forms or panels.  `Draggable` looks like it would be better suited subclassing Panel rather than using/implementing one interally.

Comment: okay sir ill add the main class

Comment: Are you getting the exception on the line that is commented out at the top of Class Main?  If so, your problem is probably because that line is executed _before_ the constructor so the `ControlPanel` is not created yet.  You can't use your controls until after they have been created in `InitializeComponents`

Comment: hello sir @ChrisDunaway I'm getting the `Exception` after the constructor when I assigned the value of ctrlPanel object to the passed parameter. here's the line: `AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseDown, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseDown)`

Comment: Are you talking about the contructor for `Class Draggable`?  The line in `Class Main` is calling the `Draggable` constructor, passing in `ControlPanel`.  `ControlPanel` is null because it has not been created yet.  In this line:  `Dim draggablePanel As New Draggable(ControlPanel) 'shows exception`, ControlPanel is null because it has not yet been created.

Comment: is it not really created? i created the panel in the designer... so im thinking the `ControlPanel` panel is really declared :( im really sorry sir @ChrisDunaway if im not getting your point. I used the same method with my `Main` form like this `Dim draggablePanel As New Draggable(Me)` it works perfectly when I use the form directly.. but when I switched to use panel, it says there it's null :(

Comment: When you drag the Panel onto the form in the designer, VS puts a line into the designer.vb file in the InitializeComponent method.  Until that method is executed, the ControlPanel has not yet been instantiated.  The line of code `Dim draggablePanel As New Draggable(ControlPanel) 'shows exception` gets executed before that happens.  To fix it, change that line to `Dim draggablePanel As  Draggable`  And then in Form_Load _after InitializeComponents_ put this line:  `draggablePanel = New Draggable(ControlPanel)`

Comment: okay sir @ChrisDunaway let me try that. i was hoping to avoid using `Form_Load`

Comment: sir @ChrisDunaway your suggestion worked for me.. thanks for your help. I really thought of using `Form_Load` to declare the `Draggable` Class there but I'm trying to avoid it. I thought my code would look nice if I just declare it in a single line, instead of using a function to run it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir ChrisDunaway suggested to declare the class in Form_Load instead of declaring it inside the Class.

**Draggable.vb**

```
Public Class Draggable

    Dim drag As Boolean
    Dim mousex As Integer
    Dim mousey As Integer
    Dim ctrlPanel As Panel
    Dim ctrlForm As Form
    Public Sub New(ByVal TargetObject As Panel, ByVal TargetForm As Form)
        ctrlPanel = TargetObject
        ctrlForm = TargetForm
        Try
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseDown, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseDown)
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseMove, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseMove)
            AddHandler ctrlPanel.MouseUp, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ThisForm_MouseUp)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

**Main.vb**

```
Public Class Main

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim draggablePanel As New Draggable(ControlPanel, Me)
    End Sub
```

**Update**

I tried adding `Public Sub New()` and wrote the code after `InitializeComponent()` and I still got the same effects. :D

```
    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim controlBar As New ControlBar(Me, pnlControlBar, btnClose)
End Sub
```

Thank you so much sir for your suggestion...